# OmniAuth with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I am trying to set up OmniAuth with Devise specifically to login with Facebook. I have followed all the instructions here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

However, when I click on the link to sign in with Facebook, I am just redirected to a blank page and not redirected back to my app. On the console, I see the following

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 12:36:40 -0400
I, [2014-08-17T12:36:40.609150 #86474]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-17 12:36:40 -0400
I, [2014-08-17T12:36:40.625593 #86474]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
```

It does not seem like the callback functions and Facebook does not seem to be authenticating my request. Is there anything else I need to do for this to work?